# Read and write complex numbers from a file in C++ (translation from C)?

Tags: c++, class, oop, io

I have a big problem. I get a task in which I should write a program in C++, which I previously write in C. This program in C++ must read complex numbers from a file and write them. I must create a class and real and imaginary parts must be private. I also must create operators << and >>. I don't know what I should do. This is my input file
data.txt

```
(2.3,5) (7.12,-2.91) (7.99,8)
(5,3.25)
```

My output file should be
result.txt

```
2.3, 5
7.12 -2.91
```

In C I use these functions

```
void readZ(FILE *wp, double *a, double *b)
{
    char c;  
    assert(fscanf(wp,"%c%lg%c%lg%c%c",&c,a,&c,b,&c,&c));

}
int writeZ(FILE *wp, double complex z)
{    
    fprintf(wp, "%.2f, %.2f\n", creal(z), cimag(z));

    return 1;
}
```

Now I must do this in C++
This is my code
main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include "read.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream inFile;
    ostream  outFile;

    char c;
    ifstream read(argv[1]);
    if (!read)
        { cerr << "Open error: " << argv[1] << endl; exit(1);}
    ofstream write(argv[2]);
    if(!write) { cerr << "Open error: " << argv[2] << endl; exit(2);}
    while(read.get(c)) 
        write.put(c);

    Complex_num x1;
    read >> x1;
    write << x1;

    inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

read.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std;

class Complex_num {
    double real, imag;
public:
    Complex_num(){
    real=0;
    imag=0;
    }


    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Complex_num&)
    {
        cout << real << '.' << imag << ',' << ' ';
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Complex_num&){
        char c;
        cin>>c>>&real>>c>>&imag>>c>>c; 
    }
};
```

read.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib> 
#include "read.h"

using namespace std;

Complex_num::Complex_num(double r, double i)
{
    real=r;
    imag=i;
}
```

I have so many errors I dont even know what I should do

```
g++ -c read.cpp -Wall
In file included from read.cpp:4:0:
read.h: In function ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Complex_num&)’:
read.h:18:17: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Complex_num::real’
         cout << real << '.' << imag << ',' << ' ';
                 ^~~~
read.h:8:12: note: declared here
     double real, imag;
            ^~~~
read.h:18:32: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Complex_num::imag’
         cout << real << '.' << imag << ',' << ' ';
                                ^~~~
read.h:8:18: note: declared here
     double real, imag;
                  ^~~~
read.h:19:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
read.h: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Complex_num&)’:
read.h:22:18: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Complex_num::real’
         cin>>c>>&real>>c>>&imag>>c>>c;
                  ^~~~
read.h:8:12: note: declared here
     double real, imag;
            ^~~~
read.h:22:28: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Complex_num::imag’
         cin>>c>>&real>>c>>&imag>>c>>c;
                            ^~~~
read.h:8:18: note: declared here
     double real, imag;
                  ^~~~
read.h:23:5: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
     }
     ^
read.cpp: At global scope:
read.cpp:8:1: error: prototype for ‘Complex_num::Complex_num(double, double)’ does not match any in class ‘Complex_num’
 Complex_num::Complex_num(double r, double i)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from read.cpp:4:0:
read.h:7:7: error: candidates are: constexpr Complex_num::Complex_num(Complex_num&&)
 class Complex_num {
       ^~~~~~~~~~~
read.h:7:7: error:                 constexpr Complex_num::Complex_num(const Complex_num&)
read.h:10:5: error:                 Complex_num::Complex_num()
     Complex_num(){
     ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: do them one by one. Start with the first. What is not clear about it? You probably forgot to give the argument a name and then you want to use members of that argument...

Comment: you should friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Complex_num&); in class and then write definition after class for a friend function.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out , const Complex_num& num) 
    {
        out << num.real << '.' <<num.imag << ',' << ' '; return out;
    }

Comment: You should probably not just port your C code straight off. Use [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read.h:18:17: error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘Complex_num::real’
         cout << real << '.' << imag << ',' << ' ';
```

Your friend operator functions are not member functions, so they dont have access to member variables. You should make use of their parameters:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  const Complex_num& c)
{
    os << c.real << '.' << c.imag << ',' << ' ';
    return os;
}
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Complex_num& cn){
    char c;
    is>>c>>cn.real>>c>>cn.imag>>c>>c; 
    return is;
}
```

Comment: I think you should also return os and is because of function return type

Comment: ahh :-) I probably have not reloaded to see it, I see I changed your edit slightly